# How to access AU Response sent from Server side at Client Side

Tags: zk

I want to know AU Responses pushed from server to Client in ZK at client side(i.e in ZUL). Searched alot not able to find any hint :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use zAu.cmd0 or zAu.cmd1 depending on your requirement. Refer to [processing Au Responses](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Client-side%20Reference/Communication/AU%20Responses) section of ZK Client side reference guide.

Comment: I went through the page din't quiet understand, can you please explain with example?

Answer (score 1):

Using the (global) [Clients](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/util/Clients.html) object you can send responses from the server to the client.
Then using already mentioned zAu.cmd0 and zAu.cmd1 javacript objects you can define the functions to [process those responses](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Client-side%20Reference/Communication/AU%20Responses).

At the server side to send a response to the server (Java):

```
AuResponse response = new AuResponse("myClientHandler", new Object[]{"hello ","world"});
Clients.response(response);
```

At the client-side for you could define something like (Javascript):

```
zAu.cmd0.myClientHandler = function (greet, person) { 
    alert(greet + person);
};
```